# error while loading shared libraries: librocksdb.so.6.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, rocksdb

I am at my wits' end with this issue because I have no idea what is wrong with my compiler. I am trying to run some C++ code using cmake on Ubuntu 21, and I get this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: librocksdb.so.6.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now here's the thing: I have rocksdb installed (via apt), but only the following:

```
ls -l /lib/librocksdb*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21315638 Dec 10  2020 /lib/librocksdb.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Dec 10  2020 /lib/librocksdb.so -> librocksdb.so.6.11.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Dec 10  2020 /lib/librocksdb.so.6 -> librocksdb.so.6.11.4
```

I know the path is the correct one and is recognised by `ld` since it works with my other shared libraries. There is clearly a version mismatch since my compiler is trying to find 6.12, but I have no idea how to fix it and get the correct version. Things I tried so far:

- clearing caches
- reinstalling
- building from source (does not generate these library names, even with the correct branch)
- creating symlinks (still gives me the same error)
- setting `find_library(rocksdb NAMES librocksdb.so.6 REQUIRED)` in my CmakeLists.txt (also tried with 6.11)

What am I doing wrong and why am I getting this error? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This error is because a binary was built against 6.12, but it's not found at run time. Only three possible reasons: 1) this binary was not built on this machine, it was downloaded or obtained from somewhere else, and it was built against a version 6.12 which you do not have 2) you compiled and linked this, against version 6.12 that's installed in some non-standard location that was found at compile time but not runtime 3) an army of malicious gnomes has invaded your computer and is causing trouble. Unfortunately your question has insufficient information to determine which case it is.

Comment: I did indeed build a binary of 6.12 a long time ago, but I deleted it - why is the linker still searching for it and how do I fix this? The code is being compiled on the same server. It sounds also weird to me that the compiler still sees the version 6.12, since I searched extensively for the library, clean reinstalled everything and now I have no other installations than the one generated by apt

Comment: Whatever is still being invoked has not been rebuilt against the current version of the shared library. So your first step would be to scroll up and inspect the error message, closely, to determine which binary is being executed, that results in this error. This error message does not pop out of thin air, but only in response to running an executable binary. So, your first step is to determine exactly what binary it is. Your second step will be to do whatever needs to be done to recompile the binary against the current version of the shared library.

Comment: you were ultimately right - there were some old headers under /include, which I did not find because I was looking for .so files. now all is good and I can't believe I wasted two hours on this. thanks for the motivation and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I had some old header files under my /include directory and the wrong library was being linked at compile time